# Error in building a Package (ppl_detection)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I was trying to install this package from source :

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ppl_detection

I cannot build the package. Apparently, there is some dependency error. It says,

[rospack] couldn't find dependency [pcl_visualization] of [ppl_detection]

What can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10327/error-in-building-a-package-(ppl_detection)/) by [Deepak](https://answers.ros.org/users/607/deepak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
It is complaining about a missing dependency in your package.
It needs the package "pcl_visualization"

You might want to confirm if you do not have the package "pcl_visualization".

```
 roscd pcl_visualization
```

If you cannot find it, you would have to obtain it from this source 
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_visualization

---

Originally posted by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) with karma: 207 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-12-01**:
More specifically, "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-perception_pcl_addons" should solve the issue (if you're on electric).

**Comment by [Deepak](https://answers.ros.org/users/607/deepak/) on 2011-06-21**:
Thanks. I had tried that out. I went back to ubuntu 10.10 from 11.04. That solved the problem.